# How can I temporarily disable creation of QGIS project backup files (.qgs~) with Python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Is it possible to temporarily disable the creation of QGIS project backup files (*.qgs~) with Python?

I'm trying to save QGIS projects in Microsoft SharePoint, where the creation of *.qgs~ files is not allowed. SharePoint has it's own file version handling, why backups are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to disable that backup feature but a workaround could be to **delete** it before you save it to sharepoint by using the following in the **Python Console**:

```
import os
path = QgsProject.instance().fileName()
os.remove(path + "~")
```

---

*Personally, I would not recommend this as I am not a fan of deleting files, particularly backups!*

Comment: In SharePoint - per default - the creation of files with extension qgs~ is not allowed. I'm using WebDAV to open qgs project-files directly from Windows Explorer. When i try to save my changes, i get an error because the backup file cannot be saved.

Comment: How can you allow the creation of this file in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still an issue 3 years down the track, but if one accesses  Sharepoint via OneDrive in Windows Explorer there don't appear to be any problems creating .qgs~ files, whether in 2.18, 3.4, 3.8, 3.10...